# how do you open a class in parental class without affecting to other sub-classed instances in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Let's say you have this Base class you need to extend.

```ruby
class Base
  class Child
    def im
      "from base child"
    end
  end

  def initialize
    @child = Child.new
  end

  def test
    @child.im
  end
end
```

For a regular case, you just need to extend the Base class and add methods just for its class.

```ruby
class A < Base
  # add methods 
end
```

However, if a sub-class wants to change behaviours of the parental inner class like this, it doesn't work.   I think it's because Base#initialize calls `Child.new`. (not B calls)

```ruby
class B < Base
  class Child
    def im
      "from b child"
    end
  end
end

puts B.new.test # "from base child"
```

If I change to `class Base::Child`, other sub-class instances will be affected.

```ruby
class B < Base
  class Base::Child
    def im
      "from b child"
    end
  end
end

puts A.new.test # "from b child"
puts B.new.test # "from b child"
```

If I wanted to have A and B behave like below, how should I open the inner class in class B? (or should I make changes in Base?)

```ruby
class B < Base
  class ????? Child
    def im
      "from b child"
    end
  end
end

puts A.new.test # "from base child"
puts B.new.test # "from b child"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is very unconventional in Ruby because nested classes are not inherited.

When you do the following

```
class B < Base
  class Child
  end
end
```

there are two possibilities: either you get the `Child` from `Base` or `Child` is not found and is considered a new constant. In this case, Ruby actually sees `Child` as a new constant (I'm guessing to prevent accidentally monkey patching the `Child` in the parent class) so you aren't opening `Base::Child` at all, you're defining an entirely separate class! Just try it:

```
B::Child == Base::Child
# false!
```

If they were equal, which is what you get by specifying `Base::Child`, you get the problem you noted in your question: modifying `Child` in the subclass modifies it for all subclasses. But again, this is expected because *nested classes are not inherited*. Either there is only one `Child` that all subclasses share or each class has its own `Child` that is completely unrelated to `Base::Child`.

However it is possible to make nested classes inherited by using metaprogramming and the `inherited` hook. Like I said, this is unconventional, so it will probably weird out other Rubyists who read your code. But if you really need to do it, here's how:

```
class Base
  class Child
    def im
      "from base child"
    end

    def common
      "shared by all subclasses"
    end
  end

  def self.inherited subclass
    # define a new Child class that inherits from Base::Child
    subclass.const_set "Child", Class.new(self::Child)
  end

  def initialize
    @child = self.class::Child.new
  end

  def test
    puts @child.im
    puts @child.common
  end
end

class A < Base
   # now this is opening Child, but not Base::Child! Rather A::Child < Base::Child
   class Child
     def im
       "from a child"
     end
   end
end

class B < Base
  # same here, opening a subclass of Base::Child so we can make changes but still share behavior with Base::Child
  class Child
    def im
      "from b child"
    end
  end
end

A.new.test
# from a child
# shared by all subclass
B.new.test
# from b child
# shared by all subclasses
```

Comment: never knew about "inherited" hook at all. super nice answer!

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured it out.  Base should call `self.class::` on to the Child.new call

```ruby
class Base
  class Child
    def im
      "from base child"
    end
  end

  def initialize
    @child = self.class::Child.new
  end

  def test
    @child.im
  end
end

class A < Base
end

class B < Base
  class Child
    def im
      "from b child"
    end
  end
end

puts A.new.test
puts B.new.test
```

Comment: You aren't opening `Base::Child` at all. `B::Child` is a completely new class. Any subclass of `Base` will either need to completely redefine `Child` (as you do here) or not touch `Child` at all.